# MySQL Query to track transaction from 5 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures, view

I have 3 tables in my db, the scenario is inventory is entered into the database with reference to invoice no/po number, then users request for inventory and admin assign the items from specific invoices_items/po_items.

I need query to get when an invoice number is entered into the database and what quantity of items is this invoice has. then when when admin issue items from this issue. in other words i have to tracked inventory transactions with reference to invoice/po number.

I have following structure of tables,

table - po_reference

```
+----------------+-------------------------+--------------------+--------+---------------------+
| po_refrence_id | po_reference_name       | requested_quantity | cost   | created_on          |
+----------------+-------------------------+--------------------+--------+---------------------+
|              6 | Dell Computer 000001256 |                 14 |  15000 | 2015-02-18 10:36:33 |
|             11 | Dell Computer 000001257 |                 50 | 150000 | 2015-02-18 10:38:33 |
+----------------+-------------------------+--------------------+--------+---------------------+
```

table - po_reference_details

```
+-------------------------+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+
| po_reference_details_id | po_refrence_id | quantity_requested | quantity_received | quantity_outstanding | remarks               |
+-------------------------+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+
|                       6 |              6 |                 20 |                14 |                    6 | 6 items are short.... |
|                       8 |             11 |                 60 |                50 |                   10 | 10 items are short... |
+-------------------------+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+----------------------+-----------------------+
```

table - stock

```
+----------+----------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+------------+-----------+---------+--------------+---------+-------------+----------------+------------------+
| stock_id | quantity | created_on          | created_by | updated_on          | updated_by | module_id | item_id | main_unit_id | unit_id | category_id | po_refrence_id | startup_quantity |
+----------+----------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+------------+-----------+---------+--------------+---------+-------------+----------------+------------------+
|      290 |       35 | 2015-02-18 02:15:00 | NULL       | NULL                | NULL       |         1 |     286 |           94 |      24 |          47 |              6 |               50 |
|      291 |      110 | 2015-02-18 00:00:00 | NULL       | 2015-02-18 00:00:00 | NULL       |         2 |     286 |           94 |      24 |          47 |              6 |               10 |
+----------+----------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+------------+-----------+---------+--------------+---------+-------------+----------------+------------------+
```

and request_stock_bridge

```
+--------------------------+------------+----------------+------------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------+
| stock_requests_bridge_id | request_id | po_refrence_id | quantity_on_hand | issued_date         | remarks                                                            | issued_quantity | main_unit_id |
+--------------------------+------------+----------------+------------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------+
|                        8 |         78 |              6 |               44 | 2015-02-18 06:49:34 | items are short , giving you 2 less, request after a week again... |               6 |           94 |
|                        9 |         79 |              6 |               42 | 2015-02-18 08:18:56 | test                                                               |               2 |           94 |
|                       10 |         80 |              6 |               35 | 2015-02-18 08:56:39 | 2 shorts....                                                       |               7 |           94 |
+--------------------------+------------+----------------+------------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

and finally table - request

```
+------------+---------------+--------------------+---------------------+-----------------+--------+---------------+-----------+---------+
| request_id | department_id | quantity_requested | requested_date      | quantity_issued | status | employee_name | module_id | item_id |
+------------+---------------+--------------------+---------------------+-----------------+--------+---------------+-----------+---------+
|         76 |            54 |                  8 | 2015-02-18 00:00:00 |               0 |      0 | MTaqi       |         2 |     279 |
|         77 |            54 |                  7 | 2015-02-18 00:00:00 |               0 |      0 | MTaqi       |         2 |     279 |
|         78 |            54 |                  8 | 2015-02-18 00:00:00 |               0 |      1 | MTaqi      |         2 |     286 |
|         79 |            54 |                  2 | 2015-02-18 00:00:00 |               0 |      1 | MTaqi       |         2 |     286 |
|         80 |            54 |                  9 | 2015-02-18 00:00:00 |               0 |      1 | MTaqi         |         2 |     286 |
+------------+---------------+--------------------+---------------------+-----------------+--------+---------------+-----------+---------+
```

i have write this query but doesn't work,

```
SELECT  s.created_on, po.po_reference_name, s.startup_quantity, su.issued_date, su.issued_quantity, su.quantity_on_hand, su.remarks,po.po_refrence_id
FROM stock s, po_reference po, request r, stock_requests_bridge su
WHERE po.po_refrence_id = s.po_refrence_id
AND su.po_refrence_id = s.po_refrence_id
AND s.item_id = 286
GROUP by po.po_refrence_id
```

it returns this,

```
+---------------------+-------------------------+------------------+---------------------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
| created_on          | po_reference_name       | startup_quantity | issued_date         | issued_quantity | quantity_on_hand | remarks                                                            | po_refrence_id |
+---------------------+-------------------------+------------------+---------------------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
| 2015-02-18 02:15:00 | Dell Computer 000001256 |               50 | 2015-02-18 06:49:34 |               6 |               44 | items are short , giving you 2 less, request after a week again... |              6 |
+---------------------+-------------------------+------------------+---------------------+-----------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: No r join condition?

Comment: new to mysql, have see examples of two and tired in my case, but got lot or errors.

Comment: The general Group By rule is: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function." You have several columns violating this rule - which MySQL may handle in a bit unexpected way.